# need to make a program in python which lists all pages related to a search and filters the contact numbers from that page and prints them

Tags: python, web-scraping, blogs

so basically I really tried to make a program in python which does what the title says but there are basically no tutorials on web scraping of this kind. So I am kind of stuck at the part where I get like the pages from google and like scan them and if a contact page exists go there and scan again and print the numbers, and seperate with different websites if possible. Now I did follow a tutorial and got to something that looks like this (I know its trash but I really don't know a lot):

```
from bs4.element import NavigableString, Tag
import requests
from bs4  import BeautifulSoup
url = "https://veragallardo.com/"

r =  requests.get(url)
htmlcontent = r.content

soup = BeautifulSoup(htmlcontent, 'html.parser')

char_list = ["contact","contact-us"]
for link in all_anchors:
    if(link.get('href') != '#'):
        linkText = (link.get('href'))
        all_links.add(link)
        print(linkText)
        if char_list in linkText:
```

```
              .-.
```

Comment: This question is far too broad; there is not really anything that can be summed up in an answer that will be suitable for what you want to do. Accessing Google search results programmatically is an issue in itself, and trying to determine what is relevant contact information on a page is also hard - unless it's properly marked up with semantic HTML. You might have success applying an NLP model to try to extract names and email addresses, but be aware - this is what we've been fighting against with spam handling and obfuscation of information for 25 years.

Comment: your code is missing some information, for example, what is `all_anchors`, please provide a [mre], also yes obviously there are no tutorials on this, you don't need a tutorial anyways, you need to learn from the basics and create more complex stuff yourself, or look a the docs, there can't be tutorials for literally everything, besides you shouldn't even try to do this as mentioned above or at least you shouldn't succeed because contact info nowadays is pretty well secured behind CAPTCHAs and other stuff

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.